# RTRIM a pattern, not all the characters

Tags: sql, oracle, trim, character-trimming

I have strings like these:

```
JAPANNO
CHINANO
BROOKLYNNO
```

I want to delete the 'NO' from all of the strings. I tried this:

rtrim(string, 'NO')

but for example in the case of BROOKLYNNO, I got this:

BROOKLY.

It deletes all the N-s from the end. How can I delete just the pattern of 'NO'?
I know I can do it with substr, but the TechOnTheNet says there is a way to delete a pattern with RTRIM, and I really want to know the way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just checked [TechOnTheNet ](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php) to see if it was incorrect based on what you said, but in fact it says "The RTRIM function may appear to remove patterns, but this is **not** the case..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may consider doing a regex replacement via `REGEXP_REPLACE`, if you give a context for when `NO` should be removed and when it should not.  For example, if you wanted to remove `NO` from the ends of your strings only, we could do the following:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'no$', '', 1, 0, 'i');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TRIM(TRAILING ... FROM)`:

```
SELECT col_name,
 REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING '^' FROM REPLACE(col_name, 'NO', '^')), '^', 'NO') AS res
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=27b5256afaaafb78b13dcea46e374869)**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, maybe?

```
declare @string varchar(150) = 'BROOKLYNNO'
select LEN(@string)
select LEFT(@string,(LEN(@string)-2))
```

You can then update your column with the output from the final **select** statement, which trims the last two letters from the string.

I suppose it might be worth asking how you're getting the data that you have here, strings appended with "NO"?